# I've been struggling with figuring out how to properly path my file input. I'm using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io, bufferedreader

Exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException. I've tried multiple things, and even tried pasting it almost everywhere. I figured that I could possibly use File input stream, but I'm still lose as of now. I appreciate any explanations. Thanks. The goal of this program is to parse a file with Student names and grades, then organize them into the median, best, and worse scores, while outputting them as individual files.

```
    //String path = "C:/Users/Rob/Documents/";
    FileReader parseFile = new FileReader("input.txt");

    BufferedReader parseText = new BufferedReader(parseFile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file will always stay in the same location, you can use the answer above, but if it's put on a different OS (e.g. Unix) the / character will not work as expected. For that reason, I would use

```
FileReader parseFile = new FileReader(new File("input.txt").toAbsolutePath());
```

This code assumes that the input.txt is in the same directory as your application. If it is not, you can't use this.

If you are going to use this to parse student grades, I suggest not using FileReader or BufferedReader altogether. NIO has a `readAllLines(URI);` function which returns a `List<String>`:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("input.txt").toAbsoluteFile().toURI());
```

This code will still throw an `IOException`, but it does the job easily, and I find it a lot easier to use.

Alternatively you can debug reasons an `IOexception` might be thrown and prevent them using the `File` API. For example:

```
public static String debugConnectionsToFile(File file) {
        if(!file.exists()){
            return "file does not exist!";
        }
        else if(!file.isFile()){
            return "File is not actually a file!";
        }
        else if(!file.canRead()){
            return "File cannot be read!";
        }

        else{
            try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                try {
                    br.readLine();
                    br.close(); //It is true that this statement could cause an error, but it has never happened to me before.
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return "File cannot be read by the reader!";
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                return "File cannot be found or accessed by the reader";
            }
            return "It works fine!";
        }
    }
```

You can obtain a `File` object by using the constructor `File(String filepath)`.

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Robbie I am not an expert but tell me if this works

```
FileReader parseFile = new FileReader("C:/Users/Rob/Documents/input.txt");
```

Also you have the String path commented out if you haven't noticed XD.
Best of luck mate!!